# Visual Studio 2012 not closing my applicationhost.config properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

`Visual Studio 2012` is not closing my `applicationhost.config` file properly.  And then when this happens my web projects don't want to load.  I have created an `ASP.NET MVC 4` project.

The closing tag of configuration element doesn't close then it looks all weird, for example:

```
</configuratai
```

And then I have to fix it by spelling configuration correctly.  When I do this I just have to reload my web projects then it works.

Why does it do this?

Comment: you may have accidentally removed the `on>` part, or may be you have copied the config file from some where else and didn't copied fully?

Comment: I don't touch these files. When I try to run it through VS then I get an error saying that IIS Express could not be started. Then I go look at the config and see that it was not properly closed.